# .htaccess redirect from old to new domain doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

There's two **Magento** webshops. One at `olddomain.com`, the other on at `newdomain.com`. I'd like to redirect from whatever link related to the olddomain to the homepage of newdomain.com`.

So far, I've changed the `.htaccess` file in the `/public_html/app` folder, from

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

as seen in many articles out there.

I've emptied the cache, but it still doesn't work at all. What am I missing here or is my approach insufficient?

Comment: How does the `app` folder relate to the document_root. Where's the access.log, error.log and rewrite.log?

Comment: @mario please see the comment I've added below.

Comment: Please see the [**edit** link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42188684/edit) we have above.

Comment: All I had to do was to append the Redirect 301 to the end of the proper htaccess file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all move your .htaccess file to /public_html/
Try to generate new .htaccess file from http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: Yeah, I can see I've made a mistake by editing the one in the app, and not the one in the public_html. After opening the right one, I can see that there is already a section for rewrite engine. Here I've modified the original `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.old.com/$1 [R=301,L]` to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]`, but there is no result after cache clear.